# What's wrong with this demonstration? (1 = -1)

Tags: analysis, fake-proofs

What's wrong with this demonstration?:

$$A \iff 1 = 1^1$$
$$A \implies 1 = 1^\frac{2}{2}$$
$$A \implies 1 = (1^2)^\frac{1}{2}$$
$$A \implies 1 = ((-1)^2)^\frac{1}{2}$$
$$A \implies 1 = (-1)^\frac{2}{2}$$
$$A \implies 1 = (-1)^1 = -1$$

So finaly we get 
$$1 = -1$$

Comment: Your violating order of operations. $((-1)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=(1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Parenthesis before exponents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property $\forall p\in \mathbb Z\forall q\in \mathbb N\left(a^{p/q}=(a^p)^{1/q}\right)$ doesn't work for negative $a$.

Howevever $\forall p\in \mathbb Z\forall q\in \mathbb N\left(q\text{ is odd}\implies a^{p/q}=(a^p)^{1/q}=(a^{1/q})^p\right)$ is true for all $a\in \mathbb Z\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: **+1** Nice answer GG. I've been reading up on differentiability and think I've got it sorted. Thanks for your help the other day.

Comment: @FlybyNight Anytime and thanks. I had already up voted you, so no (+1) retribuition ^_^

Answer (score 1):

One massive problem is that you assume that $\left(x^2\right)^{1/2} \equiv x$.

**Here's a counter example:** If $x=-2$ then $x^2=(-2)^2=+4$. Finally $(+4)^{1/2} = \pm 2$.

Clearly $-2$ is not equal to both $+2$ and $-2$ at the same time. There must be a problem!

Note that there is a big difference between $x^{1/2}$ and $\sqrt{x}$. The symbol $x^{1/2}$ represents the solutions to the equation $y=x^2$ while the symbol $\sqrt{x}$ represents the unique, real, positive solution to $y=x^2$. In a similar way $\sqrt[4]{1}=1$ while $1^{1/4} = \{\,\pm 1,\pm\operatorname{i}\,\}.$

Answer (score 0):

The core problem: the squaring function defined on the line is not 1-1.