# Is $f$ differentiable at $(x,y)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am working on a practice question, and I am not sure if what I have done would be considered, 'complete justification'. I would greatly appreciate some feedback or helpful advice on how it could be better etc. The question is here:

Let $f: \mathbb {R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ be a function defined by:

$$ \
 f(x,y) =
  \begin{cases}
   \frac{\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} & \text{if } (x,y) \ne (0,0) \\
   1       & \text{if } (x,y) = (0,0)
  \end{cases}
$$

Is $f$ diff'ble at $(x,y) = (0,0)$?

Here is what I have:

By definition, $f(x,y)$ is diff'ble at $(0,0)$ if

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)= \frac{f(x,y) - [f(0,0) + f_{x}(0,0)(x-0) + f_{y}(0,0)(y-0)]}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = 0\tag{*}$$

Since $f(x,y)$ is piecewise, $f_{x}(0,0)$ and $f_{y}(0,0)$ is derived from 1st principles:

So, $$\begin{align}f_{x}(0,0) &= \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{\frac{\sin((0+h)^2 + (0)^2)}{(0+h)^2 + (0)^2} - f_{x}(0,0)}{h} \\
&=  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{\sin(h^2)}{h^2} - 1}{h}\\
&=  \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{\sin(h^2) - h^2}{h^3} \\
&=  \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{2h \cos(h^2) - 2h}{3h^2}\end{align} $$ by L'Hopital's rule, apply this twice more I can see that the limit is $0$. Similarly, $f_y(0,0)$ is derived the same way.

Then from $(*)$, I have:

$$f_{x}(0,0) = \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{\frac{\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} - 1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} $$

From here I haven't had luck trying to get this to $0$. So instead, I try to make it easier.

Since $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ exist we must evaluate whether $f_x(x,y)$ is continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ i.e. if

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  \frac{\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} = 1 $$ then  $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$. So letting $u = x^2 + y^2$,

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  \frac{\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} = \lim_{ (x,y) \to (0,0)}  \frac{\sin(u)}{u} = 1 $$ by L'Hopital once more.

Therefore, $f$ is differentiable at (0,0).

I feel like I am perhaps not completely justifying this, because I take a short cut - but is it valid? Should I perhaps use a epsilon-delta proof? Or is there a way to work with that tricky limit I have in $(*)$?

Many thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: If you want to avoid messy calculations, you can show that for any function $f$ such that $|f(x)| \le |x|^2$, $f$ is differentiable at $0$ (and $f'(x)$ is the zero transformation) where $x\in \Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already found

$$\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(\dfrac{f(x,y) - [f(0,0) + f_{x}(0,0)(x-0) + f_{y}(0,0)(y-0)]}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right)=\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left( \dfrac{\frac{\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} - 1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right).$$

To evaluate $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left( \dfrac{\frac{\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} - 1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right)$ simplify the denominator and change the variables with $x=\rho \cos(\theta)$ and $y=\rho\sin(\theta)$ to get
$$\begin{align}\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left( \dfrac{\frac{\sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} - 1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right)&=\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\left(\dfrac{\sin(x^2+y^2)-(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\right)\\
&=\lim \limits_{\rho \to 0}\left(\dfrac{\sin\left(\rho^2\right)-\rho ^2}{|\rho| ^3}\right)\\
&=\lim \limits_{\rho \to 0}\left(\dfrac{\rho ^2+o\left(\rho^2\right)-\rho^2}{|\rho|^3}\right)\\
&=0.\end{align}$$

Comment: Sorry, just a quick comment - how did you go from your 3rd last line to the 2nd last line? I used L'Hopital's rule from the 3rd last line to get to 0 - would that be valid as well? Thanks so much.

Comment: I used the Taylor series for $\sin$. L'Hopital is fine too.

Comment: Also, when I substitute $\rho cos(\theta)$ and $\rho sin(\theta)$ and cancel out, I just get $\rho^3$, why do you have an absolute value on yours?

Comment: Because of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624377/whats-wrong-with-this-demonstration-1-1/624381#comment1315461_624381).

Comment: Is it still an issue if we assume $\rho > 0$?

Comment: @mathstudent No, because the limit is $0$, but if it happened to be, say, $1$, then you'd $-1$ one on side and $1$ on the other.